# sqlite_masterの使い方

Tags: android, sqlite

現在DBに二つのテーブルがあり、その二つのテーブルにはそれぞれ`text`というカラムがあります。その二つの`text`カラムのデータを取得してとりあえずログに表示させようとしているのですが、次のようなエラーが出てきてしまいます。

```
no such column: text (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT text FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table'
```

`sqlite_master`というようなものがあるということを先ほど知ったのですが、そもそもこれを使えば僕がやりたいような「全テーブル内で、指定したカラムのデータの取得」ということができるのでしょうか？以下に現在のコードを記します。間違いがあれば指摘していただけるとありがたいです。すみませんが、宜しくお願いします。

```
        Cursor cursor = MyDB.db.rawQuery("SELECT text FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table'", null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            Log.v("--->", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("text")));
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`SQLLITE_MASTER`](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q7) は、DBに含まれるスキーマ情報を含んでいるだけで、全てのデータを保持しているわけではありません。以下の SQL で、テーブルのDDLを得られる類のものです。

```
SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';
```

目的のためには、テーブル名を得たうえで、ここはオーソドックスに、 `union` でいいのではないでしょうか。

```
// Scheme
CREATE TABLE table1 ( id int, text varchar);
CREATE TABLE table2 ( id int, text varchar);
INSERT INTO table1 (id, text) values ( 1, "table1-1");
INSERT INTO table1 (id, text) values ( 2, "table1-2");
INSERT INTO table1 (id, text) values ( 3, "table1-3");
INSERT INTO table1 (id, text) values ( 4, "table1-4");
INSERT INTO table1 (id, text) values ( 5, "table1-5");
INSERT INTO table2 (id, text) values ( 1, "table2-1");
INSERT INTO table2 (id, text) values ( 2, "table2-2");
INSERT INTO table2 (id, text) values ( 3, "table2-3");
INSERT INTO table2 (id, text) values ( 4, "table2-4");
INSERT INTO table2 (id, text) values ( 5, "table2-5");

// DB Scheme
select id, text from (
  select id, text from table1
  union
  select id, text from table2
) where text like "%-3";
```

Result:

<kbd><kbd>id</kbd><kbd>text</kbd>  

<kbd>3</kbd> <kbd>table1-3</kbd>  

<kbd>3</kbd> <kbd>table2-3</kbd></kbd>

追加ですが、テーブルのカラム名を列挙するのには、

```
db.rawQuery("pragma table_info(" + table_name + ")", null);
```

が使えるので。組み合わせると遠回りですが実現できそうですね。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。sqlite_masterは全てのデータを保持しているわけではないのですね。ご提示のunionでなら目的が達成できそうです。この方法‌​でトライしてみたいと思います。誠にありがとうございました。追記の方法もぜひ参考にさせていただきたいと思います。